# ranking keys in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have detected several composite keys for a given table in database. How can i choose the best one between them. In another words what it is the best startegy to rank these keys. 
Thank you

Comment: What are the words? What is your mysql version? What is your database structure like? What is the result you expect from it? Can you sample code for it? This is a vague question with limited-if not none- information

Comment: @Cemal Sorry if my question was vague. Suppose i  have two database with two equivalent tables including some common attributes. These two tables describes person entity for example. Suppose i find two mutual  keys that can identify each records in table1 and table2. My question i want to rank the keys to choose the best one to link the same record in this two tables.

Comment: @bib .  I'm only seeing your comment after posting [below] but I think it still applies.  Each table will have a primary key based on uniquely identifying every row in the table.  The columns that you use to join the two table on depends on their commonalty not... I'm going to post this too

Answer (score 0):

That's not much to go on but I'm going to go out on a limb here and say...

You may be confusing primary keys with indexes.  I'm basing that on the fact that you say you have detected these composite keys (makes me think you're finding the natural primary key) but you also say you have found several of them - nope.

Primary keys are by definition unique values or unique combinations of values; they are used to uniquely identify every row in the table; and there can be only one (to quote Conner MacLeod).

Indexes are more about creating a reference that can be used to efficiently sort and scan the table by the columns that you expect to be sorting by, referencing in joins, etc; they are use-dependent; and you can have as many as you think makes sense (but don't go overboard, they can slow down things like Inserts).  There are tools out there that attempt to sniff out useful indexes based on the how they are being referenced in code.

The columns you choose to join two tables on are based entirely on where their commonality lies.  It might be all, part, or none of the primary key in either table.  If these columns are used for joins often, you may want to create an index for them.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You have reason. But suppose i have a dirty data in the table when we have deduplication records. take it a litle bit far from the strict definitin of the key in database. Suppose in this dirty table you defined two atrributes : name and nickname as one composite key. then if two records in that table have the same values for these two attributes in the key then they will be considered the same and they should be merged. After merging we can talk about the strict definition of the key as in traditional way

Comment: I would add a new, non-null, unique, integer column called user_id, employee_id, player_id, or whatever and use that as your primary key.  Otherwise all the guys named 'WIlliam Smith', nickname 'Bill', are going to get each other's paychecks :-)

Comment: By the way @bib , I added a new section to the post above regarding join columns and feel free to up-vote if you think it's useful.

Comment: Suppose we need to clean up a table. So we define a minimal key, then  for each two records that share the same value for this minimal key's properties we will then suppose that these two records are the same and then we will merge them.  So suppose we generate two minimal keys, which on we can chose to be the best in doing the clean up. One way for example is to choose the key with minimum attributes, etc.